# What does the "w" mean in open(filename, "w")?

Tags: python

I'm reading Exercise 16 of "Learn Python The Hard way" and I'm confused about `open(filename, "w")` -- what does the `"w"` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`w` stands for writing permission for the opened file

```
open(name[, mode[, buffering]])
```

Looking at the signature we can (often) understand what each argument does
more info [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in opening a filename represents the mode you're using (i.e., read-only, writable).  In this case, it's to be able to (w)rite to the file.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1):

The "W" means that you are opening the file called filename with the purpose of writing to it(hence the "W" for write.)

Answer (score 1):

The `"w"` specifies that the file is being written to. As you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), `"w"` is the mode that you use when writing to a file.

> The most commonly-used values of mode are 'r' for reading, 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists)...